# Two Fragments in one screen. Scrolling animation for two Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, coordinator-layout

I have two fragment in screen and i want second fragment(lower first fragment) covered the entire screen when it scrolling down and first fragmnet go back, and vice versa when second fragment scrolling up, first fragment appeared. Its liket toolbar and fragment do with CoordinatorLayout. How сan i do this?